# Add row selection values to Sets for comparison

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

I have a HTML Table in an Aura component with checkboxes on each row.  This table displays record data from a custom object.  I need a means of checking that certain fields from the selected records do not differ from one another.  My thought was to (on row selection) add the relevant field values from the selected records to a set to make sure that the values all match (by checking the size of each set).

My issue is that there is no persistence in the Sets so each time a row is selected, the set just contains the current selection rather than being added to even though the selected value is different.  There is probably something simple that I'm missing, I just can't see it.

**Checkbox code**

```
<td title="Select">
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="{!c.doSomething}" data-recordid="{!record.Id + ',' + record.VendorCodeRef__c + ',' + record.ShipFromCodeRef__c + ',' + record.ShipToCodeRef__c + ',' + record.ShippingMethodsRef__c + ',' + record.BuyerPlantRef__c + ',' + record.UnloadingPointRef__c}" />
</td>
```

**JS Controller**

```
doSomething: function (cmp, event, helper) {
var selectedItem = event.currentTarget;
var recordId = selectedItem.dataset.recordid;
var record = recordId.split(",");
const shipToCodes = new Set();
shipToCodes.add(record[3]);
alert(
  "Current Value is " + record[3] + " & Set size is " + shipToCodes.size
);
```